# GraphQL persisted queries in Apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

> Because persisted queries are static by definition, they also give you
>   the possibility of optimizing execution on the server for specific
>   queries, for example by hand-crafting a highly efficient database
>   query.
>   https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/persisted-graphql-queries-with-apollo-client-119fd7e6bba5

But if queries are registered automatically on server side, this mean that server must monitor new queries and adapt hand-crafting database queries, and you even don’t know what query was changed. Maybe it is better not to register automatically the requests, but to register queries manually?

So, in development environment clients can use graphql queries, and when they know that query is what they need, they can send a request to server developers to register the query or to modify an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

> Maybe it is better not to register automatically the requests, but to register queries manually?

From my experience, automatically creating persisted queries is not ideal if you want persisted queries for the *whitelisting* security aspect. Normally you have some manual script to synchronize or cut a set of persisted queries from your client that you then put into your server. At the build/deploy time this would make the most sense.

---

There has been some recent work with respect to [Automatic Persisted Queries](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/improve-graphql-performance-with-automatic-persisted-queries-c31d27b8e6ea), but this is only for the performance gains (it happens on *every query* that the server processes, and the client needs to be built to handle this new flow).